# ggplot2 bar chart labels and colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm having an issue with adding labels and colours to a bar chart using geom_text.

Here's an eg of the data: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkzjN.png)

```
Season   Answer   n     freq         
Spring   Yes      103    0.77                    
Spring   No       30     0.23   
Winter   Yes      75     0.85
Winter   No       13     0.15
```

**For labels**

The labels bunch up together, rather than there being a figure at the end of each bar.

[image: (chart example)]

```
ggplot(data = a, aes(x = Answer, y = freq)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = season),stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = freq, group = Answer),
              position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), vjust = -1.5) +
    ggtitle(label = "x") +
    labs (x = "%") +
    coord_flip()
```

I would like there to be a proportion at the end of each bar, rather than them overlapping on each other.

I would also like the proportions to show as *100. So 77.0%, rather than 0.77

**For colours**

I would like to amend the colours from the standard blue and red here as well. When I add a palette with four colours each bar gets an individual  colour [image: (chart example 2)], rather than one for 'spring' and one for 'winter'. You'll see that doing this also messes up all the labels and the legend.

If I use a colour palette with two colours I get this:

> ```
> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): fill, x, y
> ```

```
ggplot(data = a, aes(x = Answer, y = freq)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = "palette"),stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent,limits= c(0, 1))+
    geom_text(aes(label = freq, group = Answer),
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
              vjust = -1.5) +
    ggtitle(label = "x") +
    labs (x = "%") +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: For the text dodging issue, I think you want the `group` variable to be "season", not "Answer".

Comment: You'll need to change fill colors via `scale_fill_manual` a la `scale_fill_manual(values = c(Winter = "purple", Spring = "green") )`

Comment: You can just drop the `group` aesthetic altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the text dodging, drop the `group` aesthetic and adjust the dodge amount. To set the fill palette, add a `scale_fill_*` call, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- data.frame(Season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Winter", "Winter"), 
                Answer = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
                n = c(103L, 30L, 75L, 13L), 
                freq = c(0.77, 0.23, 0.85, 0.15), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(data = a, aes(x = Answer, y = freq, fill = Season, label = scales::percent(freq))) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual') + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    labs(title = "x", x = "%") +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can change 0.77 to 77%? I've had a play around but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Change the aesthetic to `label = scales::percent(freq)`

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this might be easy to answer but I can't find it online. How would I change the decimal point when using the above? so if I want it to be 23.3, or 23.34, or just 23.

Comment: If you look at the source, `scales::percent` rounds for you, which is usually good ("55.81285328234891%" is mostly junk; "55.8%" is better), but if you want arbitrary precision, you'll need to write your own function to control rounding.